# AngularJS: Input Validation - How to force a 100% RegEx match?

Tags: regex, angularjs

When using the `ng-pattern="/REGEX/"` on an `input`, AngularJS checks if a part of the entered value matches the RegEx.

**How can I tell AngularJS that I want to throw an error as soon as 1 character doesn't match the RegEx?**

**Example**

- String: `4d`
- RegEx: `[a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff ]+`
- RegEx matches: `d`

(Feel free to test the RegEx here: http://regex101.com/)

Comment: Maybe you're using the wrong `regexp`. To have some help you should post the `regexp` you're using and some input data.

Comment: I checked it at http://regex101.com/#Javascript, but I also inserted it into the original post.

Comment: Could your regex be more restrictive? I don't know which kind of strings you want to validate but you could add more restrictive parameters like `^` (start of the string)

Comment: The string is supposed to contain only spaces and lower+uppercase characters and characters like ä, ü,ß, ê

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try `^` (beginning of a string) and `$` (end of a string) symbols.

So that your RegExp would look like this:

```
^[a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff ]+$
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it for me. I am still wondering why there is no AngularJS setting...

Comment: I believe AngulasJS developers desided that since you can do that in pure RegExp, there is no need to supply such API :)